# CSS position: relative affecting text position

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/xpzxysuy/2/

So I'm playing around with some basic CSS to learn it I've run into this thing where in the case of a specific div using position: relative, the default positioning of the child text becomes affected (.right, the green div on the first line). Text-align does not affect the element in this case either.

The only way to affect the text's positioning in this case is to use css on the text element itself (any of the commented out sections in .words).  Though in another div (.middle), there is text of the same class which text-align works on just fine. What is going on here?

The HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="centerDiv">
    <div id="div1"> 
       <div class="left">
           <div class="circleDiv"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="middle">
           <p class="words">Try</p>
       </div>
       <div class="right">
           <p class="words">Word</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <p class="sentences">I'm a computer.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cleanDiv">
    In the digital world there's only three things to do.
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#centerDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
}

#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: orchid;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;

    text-align: right;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

.circleDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: blue;
}

.middle {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    /*left: 5%;*/
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;

    /*
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    */

    /*
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    */

    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
    text-align: left;
}

.words {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: pink;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;

    /*
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    */

    /*
    height: 550%;
    line-height: 550%;
    */

    /*
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    */

}

.sentences {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: purple;

    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

**Edit**:
For clarification, I was originally trying to line divs up side by side.  This works using the "float: right" and "display: flex" methods I have commented out in the css.  I'm wondering why "position: relative", though it positions the div correctly, makes the text behave strangely.  That is, it's initial position should be in the top-left of the div, but instead it appears in the top right, and ignores text-align.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The text alignment works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what position: relative is doing to the text in this situation/why it is happening for a better understanding of css.  From what I see, the text in the green .right div is all the way on the right side, despite the statement for text-align: left.  It's possible to control the text with margins and paddings as I stated, but I'm just wondering why it's inherent position changes from the top left of the div to this other placement, and why suddenly text-align doesn't affect the text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some collapsing on floats:

```
.right {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Removed the `left: 40%;` and added `overflow: auto;`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by collapsing in this case and how this fix works if you can?  From what I've read, there's two types of collapsing: one of the parent element's height collapsing if everything within it is a float, and one of vertical margins collapsing on touching elements.  The first type can't be the case since .right isn't floating for this issue.  After updating the fiddle so that there's only the 3 divs left, middle, and right (http://jsfiddle.net/xpzxysuy/5/) and taking out all margins, the same problem persists.